# What if I do not remove context data from MDC?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, mdc

I know, the MDC is a map which stores the context data of the particular thread where the context is running. I am running on a situation where I want each log statement should print certain data which is not restricted to any particular thread but application specific for eg. current node name where my application is running. So i have added node name in MDC

> MDC.put("source",source_name);

As it is application specific, i don't want to remove it from MDC (if my application goes down due to some reason, any way MDC will be cleared if i am not wrong).

Just wondering, what will happen if I don't remove the key from MDC and how it will impact my application??Will there be any memory leak or anything as such??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no impact except there will be some incorrect MDC text in the log. For example, MDC is added to thread1, then any log that logged out using thread1 will have the MDC text (surely it will also depends on logback configuration).

And if I have to say, there is a slightly performance impact because MDC data is stored in ThreadLocal. As you mentioned, ThreadLocal is like a Map  using thread as key. There will be a get-like operation when logging.

And it is not likely to have a memory leak because in your case, there will be only very limited data put into MDC and the data is simply String (I suppose source_name is string).

And yes. If somehow application goes down, thread disappear, and no ThreadLocal, and no MDC.

Hope this helps.